# Prolog: Grouping common predicates in a multi-rule clause

Tags: optimization, prolog

Assuming I have the following rules in Prolog:

```
same_head():- same_costly_predicate(), a_predicate().
same_head():- same_costly_predicate(), another_predicate().
```

Should I be doing the following to optimize the code or does the compiler does it by itself in these situations?

```
same_head():- same_costly_predicate(), next_pred().
next_pred():- a_predicate().
next_pred():- another_predicate().
```

It's an optimization because in the first block of code same_costly_predicate() will be computed twice should it succeed.

Is there any article that explains stuff such as the above and helps write more efficient code?

Comment: You can also use a disjunction. Prolog does not optimise in this way as `some_costly_predicate/?` may have side effects.